# Spotfire: editing the headers of a cross table

Tags: spotfire, tabular

I've built a cross table in Spotfire with some data which is aggregated in various ways (e.g. "sum", "first", etc.).

The default headers are really ugly (e.g. "SUM(revenue)") and I would like to change them to something a bit more relatable. For example, instead of SUM(revenue), I would like to have "Total Revenue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you gave in your question, just add the bolded portion below in the Custom Expression editor:

Sum(Revenue) **AS [Total Revenue]**

With several columns, it would be:
Sum(Revenue) AS [Total Revenue], Sum(Expense) AS [Total Expense]

...and so on. You can also include special characters in your title as long as you're using the brackets

Answer (score 3):

Just edit the properties of the Cross Table (right click, properties), then type a new name into the Display Name box that I helpfully outlined with a freehand red circle! You get to that screen by clicking the little black triangle beside the column name:

[image]

Comment: That's great but every time I change something it then resets the titles to the defaults...I guess I'm gonna go with "custom expression"...

Comment: "Every time I change something"... what are you changing? You should be able to add and remove other columns through the GUI without it changing the names of columns already there.

Comment: If, for example, I move the columns up or down in the list the names reset

Comment: Strange. I can re arrange the columns using the Select Columns box (I'm assuming this is what you meant when you said up or down in the list), or by clicking and dragging, and the names remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found a way...apparently you can't change the columns that are already there but you can delete everything and set the names when you are setting up the columns.

Full details here:
http://docs.spotfire.cloud.tibco.com/spotfire/GUID-796A4E7B-6669-4F39-8746-5B73F44F342B.html

If anyone knows how to edit the titles instead of having to re-do the table every time, it would be great!